# Ipad show title-Tag of image

Tags: html, ipad

On desktop-computers I can use title-attribute of image-element as a tooltip. How can I handle this behaviour on an IPad?

Comment: How many iPad applications have you seen that used tooltips? They don't fit well in a touch UI. Let the advisory information be lost, it should be optional anyway. Focus on conveying the information better without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure, but you can get a tooltip look on an image with help of jquery tooltip. Check here. http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/tiptip-jquery-plugin

You will have to work around to get that view over an image. This plugin used for getting tooltip view for links. Also this works fine on ipad for links. Try this, might help you.